# Curl vs Python Requests (GET)

Tags: python, curl, python-requests

I'm currently modernizing a request from a bash curl to a python request. Here is before:

```
curl -X GET --header 'Accept: text/csv' 'https://URL?afterDate=1650914642000&beforeDate=2000000000000'
```

Here is the new process:

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd
import io

args = {
            'params': {'afterDate': 1650914642000, 'beforeDate': 2000000000000},
            'data': {},
            'headers': {'Accept': 'text/csv'},
            'timeout': 3600
        }
req = 'URL'

r = requests.request("GET", req, **args)

str_buffer = io.StringIO()
str_buffer.write(r.text)
str_buffer.seek(0)
df = pd.read_csv(
        str_buffer,
        escapechar="\\",
        sep=",",
        quotechar='"',
        low_memory=False
    )
```

Surprisingly, this is not working. The curl works and the requests version does not. Talking to the engineers on the other end, they are seeing all green lights and a bit of latency, but nothing very abnormal. As far as I can tell, the request just sits and does not receive the data the endpoint returns.

Additional Context:
This process is for catching a daily delta load, so the 2000000000000 param is just an arbitrarily high value and even for a single minute of time I cannot return data. The endpoint is a java based api hitting a mongo source, and there is a fair amount of latency, even on the curl request.

I'm at a loss of how to dig deeper than "It's not working on my machine", if anyone knows of anything that could help, help a guy out!

EDIT:
After 30minutes of running (it should take about 10-15 min), when I keyboardInterrupt I get this trace (this is the end):

```
  File "/home/rriley2/anaconda3/envs/env_etl/lib/python3.6/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 1839, in recv_into
    result = _lib.SSL_read(self._ssl, buf, nbytes)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Comment: Where's your `Accept` header in the Python version?

Comment: I updated the question, sorry this is an abstraction obviously.

Comment: What does "not working" mean? What happens when you run your python code? What do you expect to happen? Show an example run with actual output and explain what you want instead.

Comment: That's just it, literally nothing happens, no error until my manual timeout (1 hour) kicks in or I get bored staring at it (realistically, it should take 15min). It's just hung up.

Comment: On a side note...what is the purpose of `str_buffer`? Can you just `pd.read_csv(r.text)` directly? Also, have you tried `print(r.text)` or any other debugging to confirm if it is the request that's the problem or pandas?

Comment: I have a log step after the request and it's never touched. So I'm confident it's the request.

Comment: While figuring this out, I suggest setting `afterDate` and `beforeDate` to a smaller time window. And set the timeout to a smaller value. Print out anything that is helpful from the reply, such as the status code, the body, and the headers

Comment: Your code here doesn't have a log after the request. I guess this is taken from a larger piece of code. I appreciate that you are trying to give the minimal amount of code to show what you are doing. Still, you need to be sure that the code that you post here actually duplicates the problem you are asking about. Have you tried running this version of the code independent of your bigger project?

Comment: No worries, and yes I have. Could there be something to do with not having "content-type" headers and just the accept?